# Comparing values in text file

Tags: batch-file, conditional-statements

Hello and thanks in advance for any help offered.

I have a text file (Check_Quantities.txt) that will be giving me values that I need to act upon. The file will read exactly like this:

`Qty1=200 Qty2=201`

(the numbers will change throughout the day)

I need to write a conditional batch file that will compare the numbers and then either stop the next action from happening, or allow the next action to happen.

For example, If Qty1 < Qty2, then stop the process in its tracks, and throw a warning message up on the screen.

If Qty1 >= Qty 2, then proceed to the next action which is...

`copy c:\temp\ASNReport.txt u:\temp`

I really have minimal programming knowledge, but this seems like a simple task. Unfortunately, I've not been able to find any help on the internet, despite several hours of searching.

Thanks again,
Bart

Answer (score 3):

The command below load in the variables the values given in the file:

```
for /F "tokens=1,2" %%a in (Check_Quantities.txt) do set %%a& set %%b
```

Previous line is *equivalent* to execute the following (with the given file):

```
set Qty1=200
set Qty2=201
```

This way, you may use the values of the variables in any way you wish. For example:

```
if %Qty1% geq %Qty2% (
   copy c:\temp\ASNReport.txt u:\temp
) else (
   echo Warning message
)
```

Of course, you need to know Batch basics at least to go on...

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there are other solutions,  however this should do the job. Try this:

```
@echo off
for /f  "tokens=2,4 delims==, " %%a in ( Check_Quantities.txt ) do (        
    if %%a LSS %%b (
        echo WARNING
        goto end
    ) else (    
       copy c:\temp\ASNReport.txt u:\temp   
       echo copied ASNReport.txt
    )                       
)
:end
```

Comment: This is also awesome. Thank you so much for your help. Bart